# How to properly save an entity with one-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring jpa.

I have two entities with one-to-many relationship:

```
class Parent {
  @ID
  @Generated
  Integer id;

  @OneToMany
  Set<Child> children

}

class Child {
  @ID
  @Generated
  Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  Parent parent;
}
```

Based on my understanding of jpa relationship, we can save the parent class, and JPA will automatically save its related children. So I put together below usage code:

```
Parent parent1 = new Parent("David");

Child child1 = new Child("Jack");
Child child2 = new Child("Mary");
Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
children.add(child1);
children.add(child2);
// I purposely skipped saving each child, to rely on the saving operation of the parent 
// for child in children {
//  child = childJpaRepository.save(child);
// }


// I expect that saving parent will update each children's generated-ID
parent = parentJpaRepository.save(parent);
```

I tried above code out and discovered that each child's id field remains unset if I do this after above code:

```
for child in children {
  print(child.getId());
}
```

My question: What is the proper way of saving this relationship? Do I have to do below statements before saving the parent?

```
 for child in children {
  child = childJpaRepository.save(child);  // ??? Isn't it slow to do individual saving of each child, because DB operation is high cost??
 }
```

Comment: These are different things: saving the children, giving you back their id's. My guess is that the children are actually saved. You don't get the id's because that'd require one more database access.

Comment: If you want to cascade the save from the Parent to the Child then you need `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`.